# Qurkus define resource limits for kubernetes init containers

Tags: quarkus

I'm using quarkus 2.2.3 to build my service image and the kubernetes yaml script file.
How can I define the *resources.limits* for an init-container directly in my application.properties?

Marco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but you can open an issue on GitHub requesting the feature

Answer (score 0):

This entry from the doc might help you https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes#container-resources-management

This configuration

```
quarkus.kubernetes.resources.requests.memory=64Mi
quarkus.kubernetes.resources.requests.cpu=250m
quarkus.kubernetes.resources.limits.memory=512Mi
quarkus.kubernetes.resources.limits.cpu=1000m
```

Should result in the following yaml:

```
containers:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 512Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 250m
      memory: 64Mi
```

Comment: Hi Javier, that defines the limits for the container, not for the init containers. At least it's what I've seen in my test environment.

Comment: I'm using a kubernetes 1.21 with kind

Comment: @Marco you are right, It looks like its not supported yet https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20793

Answer (score 0):

From [the official docs](https://es.quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes), there are several options like:

```
quarkus.kubernetes.init-containers."init-containers".resources.limits.cpu
quarkus.kubernetes.init-containers."init-containers".resources.limits.memory
```